# Is there a way to add check-in comment when saving from MSWord?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, word, office, check-in

Is there any way to add a check-in comment when saving from MS Word 2010?

I was hoping to find a sharepoint funcionality that prompts a user to add a check-in comment when saving back .doc files to sharepoint from the Office interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps...

1. Check out the word document in SharePoint.
2. Open the document in MS-Word for editing.
3. Modify the document and go to File TAB.
4. There you will find "Check In" & "Discard Check Out" buttons.